# how to use jquery variable value in confirm text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Okay so I want to get the jQuery variable value in my alert box. I tried something but this is not giving me the result as expected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
        var dataString = {
            amount: $("#amount").val()
        };
        var getamt = dataString.amount;
    $.confirm({
        title: 'Confirm!',
        content: 'Are you sure you want to transfer $"'.getamt.'" to wallet?', // not getting the result
        buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType : "json",
                        url: "add-funds-process.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: true,
                  beforeSend: function(){
                            $("#submit").hide();
                            $("#loading-rent").show();
                            $(".message").hide();
                  },
                        success: function(json){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $(".message").html(json.status).fadeIn();
                                $('#wallet').html('$' + json.wallet);
                                $('#balance').html('$' + json.balance);
                                $("#submit").show();
                                $("#loading-rent").hide();
                            },1000);
                        }
                    });
        },
        cancel: function () {
          $.alert('<span style="font-size: 23px">Upgrade Cancelled!</span>');
        }
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Can any of you expert guys help me with this? I will be thankful.

Comment: use `+` instead of `.`... and `var getamt = dataString.amt;` will throw an error.

Comment: seems like you're trying to use php lol. But yes, do what Kartikeya said.

Comment: thanks.. that solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using php operater`.`with javascript. in javascript `+` is use for concating the variable with string.

Run this example it may help you....

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $.confirm({
        title: 'Confirm!',
        content: 'Are you sure you want to transfer "' + $("#amount").val()  + '" to wallet?', // not getting the result
        buttons: {
        confirm: function () {
          $.alert('confirm');
        },
        cancel: function () {
          $.alert('<span style="font-size: 23px">Upgrade Cancelled!</span>');
        }
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.2.0/jquery-confirm.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.2.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>

<button id="submit">Hello</button>
<input type="text" id="amount" placeholder="Enter the amount">
```

Comment: the problem was already solved with the comments above.. thanks for your time anyways :)